# Classifying dataset with few positive results, how to handle false positive paradox?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, unbalanced-classes

I'm working on a classification task with data that have only 2% of positive results and it's hard to get high true positive result with low false positive. Maybe you know how to handle such data, or any tips and tricks?

I tried Boosted Tree Forest, Logistic Regression, Random Forest and some others.

Comment: Some basic data analysis might help here.  You say the rate is 2% overall, but what about by various predictor variables?  Suppose you convert all continuous predictors to "percentiles", then check the rate in each percentile.  For categorical variables, take the rate in each category.  Does the rate vary across any variables?  This won't pick up interaction effects, but it is a good start.  For best predictions, you need at least some groups where the rate is more like 50% or higher.

Comment: Thank you but each vector has about 32 variables, and the best that I get till now without losing more than 20% of true positive result it 5 % probability, but thank you I will try to check other variables or some simple combinations.